# dns does not work from different drive letters

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, hard-drive, hosts

```
C:\>ping localhost

Pinging Vextor [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
Control-C
^C
C:\>f:
F:\>ping localhost
Ping request could not find host localhost. Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: What results do you get if you try to ping another machine?

Comment: same results ... same results with nslookup aswell

Comment: What about browsing to different drive letters besides F:, such as a CDRom or flash drive?

Comment: all drive letters do not work except for C:\ .. i have a usb drive attached an another large drive attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all your windows networking woes, try

`netsh winsock reset`

and reboot

Answer (score 0):

There's a first for everything :-)

Are you sure you are running the same ping (check your path environment variables also) and can you list the contents of F:\? I.e. is the F: partition online/accessible?

Comment: how do you check if the f: partition is online accessible ? I did check the location of ping.exe -- it is running the same ping... and it is running from c:\windows\system32 ... i even tried to run c:\windows\system32\ping.exe from the f:\

Comment: So you can get a dir from F:\ and copy & run files on it?

Answer (score 0):

Never seen anything like this, and I'm totally unable to reproduce it *anywhere*.

The only plausible reason I can see would be if you have an executable file called `ping` (`ping.exe`, `ping.bat`, `ping.vbs`...) on your F: drive, and that gets called instead of the standard system ping utility. Other than that, I have no clue at all...

Comment: yes it is very strange. my other machines work fine ... just this particular server doesnt like dns on different drive letters. I've tried rebooting disconnecting drives and still do not work